# Pyspark does not allow me to create bucket

Tags: pyspark

Pyspark does not allow me to create bucket.

```
(
    df
    .write
    .partitionBy('Source')
    .bucketBy(8,'destination')
    .saveAsTable('flightdata')

)
```

---

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 df.write.bucketBy(2,"Source").saveAsTable("table")

AttributeError: 'DataFrameWriter' object has no attribute 'bucketBy'

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `bucketBy` is only supported in spark 2.3.0
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/readwriter.html#DataFrameWriter.bucketBy

You could try creating a new bucket column

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import Bucketizer
bucketizer = Bucketizer(splits=[ 0, float('Inf') ],inputCol="destination", outputCol="buckets")
df_with_buckets = bucketizer.setHandleInvalid("keep").transform(df)
```

and then using `partitionBy(*cols)`
`df_with_buckets.write.partitionBy('buckets').saveAsTable("table")`