# Join optimisation in case of unbalanced datasets

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I have two sets to be LEFT joined:

Dataset A: ~10000 parquet files each 300 KB

Dataset B: ~50000 parquet files each 30 MB

I want to join on a string column which is common in both datasets, say "name".

One important thing is each row in Dataset A has a match in Dataset B. But Dataset B contains many other rows.

The usual join function takes very long and fails on most cases. So I am asking if there can be an optimisation? For example, is partitioning Dataset B alphabetically on "name" column a good idea? Broadcast join will not work because Dataset A is not small enough.

Comment: have you tried bucketing ?

Comment: no, can you expand please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can [bucketize](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.bucketBy) your files before joining, it is probably better. 
Otherwise, you need one more writting step to use bucketing.

```
df_A.write.format('parquet')
...     .bucketBy(10, 'name')
...     .mode("overwrite")
...     .saveAsTable('bucketed_table_A'))

df_B.write.format('parquet')
...     .bucketBy(10, 'name')
...     .mode("overwrite")
...     .saveAsTable('bucketed_table_B'))
```

Bucketing allows you to pre-shuffle your data. 
Both dataframa_A and datafram_B should have the same number of buckets. The choice of number of bucket is a difficult "art" and depends on your data and your configuration.

Then, you read your bucketized data and you join them on "name".

```
spark.table('bucketed_table_A').join(
    spark.table('bucketed_table_B'),
    on='name',
    how='left'
)
```

Doing that, you transfer the computing time from join step to write/bucketize step. But do it once, and then you can re-use it many times.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am using AWS Glue, the Spark version is lower than 2.3 so it doesnt support BucketBy. Do you know any alternative to this?

Comment: What About partition by? Can you use it? Any column you could use as a partition?

Comment: Is the effect same as BucketBy for the join? I can create a column with the starting letter of the "name" column.

Comment: that's potentially a good idea I think. The effect is not the same but it can produce some unexpected results probably.

Comment: This page suggest an alternative to BucketBy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49398687/pyspark-does-not-allow-me-to-create-bucket
I will try this.

Comment: Another improvement is to "compact" dataframes A and B. 300kb per file is too few. Reduce the number of files, increase the size. Ideal size is around 200-300mb

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184152/discussion-between-steven-and-sinan-erdem).